# How to focus on a ToolStripTextBox (one of the items in a ToolStripDropDownButton.DropDownItems collection) when the drop down opens

Tags: winforms

I'm building the DropDownItems of a ToolStripDropDownButton programmatically. The first field is always a ToolStripTextBox (which users can type into to filter the following items).  I want the ToolStripTextBox to have focus as soon as the drop down opens so that user can:

1. Click on the ToolStripDropDownButton
2. Begin typing (to filter the items)

However, when I try to focus on the ToolStripTextBox (within the DropDownOpened event handler):

```
Dim v As ToolStripTextBox = DirectCast(tsbForms.DropDownItems(0), ToolStripTextBox)
Me.ActiveControl = v.Control
```

I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Invisible or disabled control cannot be activated'
```

Here's a screen shot of the dropdown so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image]

Currently the textbox at the top doesn't have focus and you have to click in it before you can start typing in the filter.

FYI I've tried testing the Visibility of the ToolStripTextBox before setting ActiveControl and it is True in this event.  I've tried performing the operation a few other events and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting focus worked for me:

```
Dim v As ToolStripTextBox = DirectCast(tsbForms.DropDownItems(0), ToolStripTextBox)
v.Focus()
```

I used the DropDownOpened event of the parent ToolStripDropDownButton.

Comment: The very first thing I tried was to call Focus() but Intellisense didn't offer it as an autocomplete.  I figured that it didn't support Focus() (because ToolStrip controls are lightweight) and so looked for alternative, hence Me.ActiveControl.  But yes, Focus works... Intellisense doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: @RAM The intellisense works on Visual Studio 2012.  It didn't work for me on Visual Studio 2017.